# Retrieving list of signing identities via API

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, security, certificate

This is related to macOS.

I need to retrieve list of signing identities (certificate + private key) imported and available on Keychain using API from inside native Mac app. I can run a following command line and parse the result:

```
> /usr/bin/security find-identity -v -p codesigning
> 
>  1) 0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF01234567 "iPhone Developer: John Doe (GTHESFW12)"
>  2) 0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF01234567 "iPhone Distribution: ABC Inc (12356DGEWS)"
> 2 valid identities found
```

But I'm looking for a way to do this via native security API. Is there way to do this?

Comment: You need to read [Keychain Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking at something close but didn't get to the right link

Comment: Good luck. It's a daunting API, but it should have everything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JamesBucanek, than you for the link! Here is resulting code using Keychain Services API. May be it will be useful for other people:

```
let query: [String: Any] = [
    kSecClass as String: kSecClassIdentity,
    kSecReturnRef as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
    kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitAll
]
var items: CFTypeRef?

// Get list of all SecIdentity from Keychain without limiting search and without any filtering applied
guard SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &items) == errSecSuccess, let array = items as? NSArray else {
    return
}

for item in array {
    let identity = item as! SecIdentity
    var certificate: SecCertificate?

    // Get SecCertificate out of SecIdentity object (it contains both SecCertificate and SecKey
    if SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identity, &certificate) == errSecSuccess {

        var commonName: CFString?
        // Print name for each certificate
        if SecCertificateCopyCommonName(certificate!, &commonName) == errSecSuccess {
            print(commonName! as String)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Saved my time, thanks a lot :)
Below also if someone looking for converting it to data : 
 let certData = SecCertificateCopyData(certificate) as Data
 print("certData : \((certData.base64EncodedString()))")